# How to change value of mysql global variable default_authentication_plugin in Amazon Aurora Serverless MySQL 5.7.12

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

I'm using Amazon Aurora Serverless MySQL cluster(MySQL 5.7) and want to change the value of global variable **[default_authentication_plugin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_default_authentication_plugin)** which is currently set to default ie. mysql_native_password

These are the commands I'm using to update the default authentication plugin

```
SET GLOBAL default_authentication_plugin = 'sha256_password'; 
SET @@GLOBAL.default_authentication_plugin = 'sha256_password';
```

But I'm getting below error

[image]

From the documentation, I can see the default_authentication_plugin is not a dynamic variable.
[image]

Also, I have checked in the DB Cluster Parameter Group the default_authentication_plugin parameter is not available there as well.

How do I change the value of the default_authentication_plugin in this case? Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Raised this issue with the AWS Support below is the reply I got.

There is no way to update value of **default_authentication_plugin** global variable as of now. But Amazon Aurora and RDS instances does supports sha256_password auth plugin.

Below command can be used to create users with sha256 hashed password.

```
CREATE USER '<username>'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH sha256_password BY '<password>';
```